# How to read integer numbers from file to an array?

Tags: c, visual-studio

An error always occurs just like (stream != null)
What does it mean?
I shoul write a program then reads numbers to an array that prints them out. Otherwise everything will be bad(

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 4

int main() {
    int i = 0, b = 0;
    int myArray[M];

    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("D:\file1.txt", "rt");

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        fscanf(myFile, "%d", myArray[i]);
    }

    fclose(myFile);

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        printf("%d", &myArray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you have any code we can look at?

Comment: i've just attached to the question

Comment: I believe you have fscanf and printf backwards, &myArray[i] should be in fscanf, myArray[i] should in printf

Comment: Still doesn't work (

Comment: what kind of output are you getting? and does the file exist?

Comment: I created a file file1.txt and filled it with 1 2 3 4 5 numbers

Comment: I can't really say exactly what the problem is without knowing what errors/output you're getting, please edit your question to contain the output